# How to recognize local and linked Material with Python

Tags: python, materials, linked-data

in blend file I have local material called "aluminium".
Then I link material called "aluminium" from from different blend file.
**How can I regonize these two?**
When I print:

```
for mat in bpy.data.materials:
        print(mat.name)
```

It prints "aluminium" twice.
When hovering over these in outliner, it shows no python tooltip.
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Look at library property**

For two ID objects of same type to have same name will be from different linked libraries

```
>>> for m in D.materials:
...     m.name, m.library
...     
('Material', None)
('Material', bpy.data.libraries['aubio_tests.blend'])
```

Can use the library as an extra key

```
>>> D.materials["Material", None]
bpy.data.materials['Material']
```

Comment: Thats it, thanks alot!

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `.name_full` to differentiate:

```py
>>> print(*[m.name_full for m in D.materials], sep="\n")
Dots Stroke
Material

>>> with D.libraries.load("E:/pixarletter.blend", link=True) as (f, imported):
...     imported.materials = ["Material"]
...     
>>> print(*[m.name_full for m in D.materials], sep="\n")
Dots Stroke
Material
Material [pixarletter.blend]
```

Comment: Thanks, thats also helpful to know!